# How to make the Response Caching worked in the wso2am-3.1.0? (am-pattern-2)

Tags: kubernetes, wso2-api-manager

**Description:**
I've already add the

```
[message_builder]
json = "org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
```

in the deployment.toml of the Gateway config chart.
But I do not understand the meaning of "maintain the standard builders on the API Dev portal node. "It's from https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/response-caching/#response-caching
What does it mean and how to make this work?

**Suggested Labels:**
Response Caching

**Affected Product Version: wso2am-3.1.0

**OS, DB, other environment details and versions: kubernetes centOS  mysql

Answer (score 0):

APIM has Default [message builders](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/configuring-message-builders-formatters/#default-message-builders) and [message formatters](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/configuring-message-builders-formatters/#default-message-formatters).
You need to configure them on devportal node like [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/configuring-message-builders-formatters/#configuring-default-message-builders-and-formatters).